# Is there a bulk method to put emails on hold?

Tags: civimail, import

Bounce processing has not been working - but I do have a list of addresses that have been bounced. What I want to do is bulk update all those matching contacts and put their emails on hold.

I cant see a way of doing that. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extra column to your spreadsheet called "On Hold" and assign it 1, another one called "hold date" and then (3 options below, choose 1):

1. import your sheet (using eileen's csv import extension) as "emails", with appropriate matching rules.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui

2. If you're brave, you could upload your sheet as it's own table and do an sql "Update" on the civicrm_email table joining your new table via the email addresses.
3. You might be able to just import your sheet as a regular contact import with your strict matching rule, if your email addresses are unique (I'm not sure whether this would work, but it might be the easiest if it does - the part I'm not sure about is whether the mapping you get would expose the is-on-hold field and on-hold-date field).

Comment: why not just import the emails (assuming unique), add to a Group, then bulk update their Comm Prefs, or does that last step not exist or not cover the OP

Comment: Sounds like how it should work, but I'm not seeing a bulk action to put on hold, only to unhold. There might be an extension that provides that action.